# How do I integrate queries to legacy databases?

Tags: migrations

I'd like to totally move to Drupal and was hoping for information.  I have an old classic asp site with webpages everywhere, not in a framework or cms or anything like that.  They're just set up like the "old way" of doing things.  Mixed code and presentation and so on.

I wanted to move to Drupal, but I need to know how to handle the legacy or new non-Mysql datasources.

For example, I have an asp page that hits a sql server database.  If I rewrite that in PHP, how do I get it into Drupal?  Do I create a module for each page I want to port over?  What do I do?  Should I not use Drupal if this is my need?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Drupal (and also Drupal answers) :) Glad to hear that you've chosen Drupal.

Although the scope of this question is pretty big, I'll try my best to answer. Feel free to ask more questions.

You might want to first check out whether Drupal fits in your requirements. You can check [Case Studies of different sites](https://drupal.org/case-studies) which were built (from scratch or migrated) on Drupal. See if it gives you any idea.

If Drupal does fit into your requirement (mostly it does), you can check if there is any [Drupal distribution](https://drupal.org/project/distributions) present which is closer to your requirement (e.g. Commerce Kickstart distribution is a customized Drupal installation which is modified to provide features for a typical e-commerce site; while OpenPublish distribution is for news/articles publishing).

You don't need to develop a module per page. If you come across any requirement, there is a popular saying which goes "There's a module for that", which just means that there is a possibility that someone else who faced the same problem came up with the solution in the form of a module. You can search the list of modules on the official [Drupal.org site](http://drupal.org/project/modules), or [drupalmodules.com](http://drupalmodules.com/), or just google it ;-)

You might also check for the [Migrate module](https://drupal.org/project/migrate), which provides out of the box support to migrate sites powered by other technologies to Drupal (with some customization).

If you get any queries in your *Journey to Drupal Land*, you're always welcomed here on StackExchange's Drupal site :)

Comment: I don't think I ever figured out the answer to this.  I have my drupal site, but I want to query an old database for information purposes and display that data on a page.  Do I create a module to do that?  I don't know of a module that will be tailored for an ancient database system.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module which can be used to query (not update) any MS SQL database. It comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports) for an online example of the [Forena Documentation](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help).

The [Sample reports and graphs](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/samples) are fully functional, such as the drill downs available on the [Master Summary with drill down](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.state_summary).

The newest 7.x-4.x version also includes a UI for either creating your reports (the **WYSIWYG report editor**) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the **WYSIWYG Query Builder**).

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.

**Note**: a [D8 branch](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/forena/tree/?h=8.x-1.x) has been started, though no (beta) release for D8 is available yet.

Comment: Thanks Pierre.  Will it work with Drupal 8?